# How to change the port of the client bound by the user in locate

Tags: udp, performance-testing, locust

#### scene

I am testing the performance of UDP server. It is implemented with `Locust` + `custom client`.

When the custom client judges the packet loss, it records the sent data and throws an exception to `Locust`.

When `Locust` catches the exception, it will stop executing the tasks behind the task set, skip the current task set and select a new task set for execution.

If there is only one task set, the current task set is re executed.

#### problem

I want to replace the socket port bound by user when `Locust` re executes the task set.

However, the port cannot be changed after the socket is bound to the port (I can't find an example on Google that can be changed.)

I tried to bind a custom client in the task set bound by user, but I received an error from `Locust`.

Is there any way to realize my demand?

#### Are there any other perspectives?

For example:

- After `Locust` catches an exception, end the current user, and then start a new user.

#### last

English is not my native language, please forgive my grammar mistakes.

Thanks for reading! It would be better if you could help.

Comment: I dont have an answer for your question, but you’re more likely to get a good answer if you focus the question on the udp-part, perhaps providing your actual code. The ”locust part” of your problem can be solved in multiple ways, maybe using an event handler http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#extending-locust or maybe just using a try-catch

Comment: I have done corresponding processing on the UDP client, but UDP is unstable and may still report errors. After the error is reported, Locust will stop the current task and execute the next task. However, because the same socket is used, it is possible to receive the data packet returned by the server before the error is reported, which will lead to the exception of my program.

Comment: So I want users to rebind a UDP client.

Or stop the error reporting user after locust receives the error report, and then restart a user.

Comment: About new users: I found relevant examples in [the connection you sent](http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#extending-locust).

Comment: Locust can add an event to execute when the user makes an error through the following code: `@events.user_error.add_listener`
But how can I add a new user?

Comment: Oh!!!
I just found this method in the runner class of locust:  `def start(self, user_count: int, spawn_rate: float, wait: bool = False):` 
I'll try

Comment: Do you really need to add a new user? Just replacing the connection with a new one (on the same user instance) should be enough.

Comment: Yes, I realized it yesterday. Therefore, I added a restart () method to the customized client, which will help me replace the socket in the same one. Thank you!!!